# Processing Authorize.net relay response with PHP

Tags: php, api, email, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am kind of a newbie when it comes to `online CC processing integration`.  I am in the `Sandbox` at `Authorize.NET` trying to `configure` my `server` to `process SIM orders` where the `payment` page `form resides` on the `Authorize.net servers` and `processes` the order.  By default it looks like the `confirmation` is on their `sites`, and `e-mails` can be configured to be sent to the buyer and the seller.  That is all working in the `Sandbox`.  However, I am trying to capture some of the order and processing information on my server using the relay response.  My processing page is accessible on my server, although I must say that I have `.htaccess` limited intermittently because it is still in `development`.  I turn that off when I am testing.

The error that I am getting is:

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card.

  This transaction has been approved.
```

`It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.`

I can't tell if they are `POSTING data` to my page or not, and I'm not really clear on what goes on the response page and how to parse the response.  I am using the `PHP SDK` provided by `Authorize.NET`.  The rest seems to be working.  I am getting `e-mails` for the buyer and the seller and the order is proccessed but I'm not capturing the information on our server.  What I would like to do is bypass their `confirmation page`, receive the relay response, create a custom confirmation and capture some of the `data` for our `database`.  I'll keep digging because I made a fair amount of progress just reading the docs.  This one is particularly useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your relay response URL publicly available and on standard port 80 or 443?  Since the POST is initiated by the Authorize.Net servers, the error you are receiving suggests it cannot connect to your server.

Comment: I figured it out.  There was an error on the page giving a "500" error.  I have to say, it is a little strange the way they have it set up.  They are POSTING to my page, where I am capturing the POST data, writing stuff to a database, and then creating a custom confirmation message, although it must be via a header redirect because it shows up on their server (their domain is in the address bar).  It all works, but apparently, any SESSION variable values are not available to my script in that case?

Comment: After I capture data and do whatever I need to do should I also redirect to my own page using a GET or is it fine the way it is.

Comment: A Javascript redirect should work for you.  For session data, check into user fields, sometimes referred to as Merchant Defined Fields, you can pass your own values and they are reflected in the response.

Comment: What I am doing it capturing the data that I sent to them in the POST that they send back to me. That works since I use that data to create a custom receipt, which is display on their server.  I am still a little confused about how they send the POST in the relay redirect.  It seems that they are using a header redirect and POSTING data in the redirect, so that the output of my page displays on their server.  It works if I pass them the data that I want to get back, but I would rather display the receipt on my server and have access to some of the SESSION data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was an error on the page giving a "500" error. I have to say, it is a little strange the way they have it set up. They are POSTING to my page, where I am capturing the POST data, writing stuff to a database, and then creating a custom confirmation message, although it must be via a header redirect because it shows up on their server (their domain is in the address bar). It all works, but apparently, any SESSION variable values are not available to my script in that case?